# Issue passing NSMutableDictionary to a method

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I've got a chunk of code that's passing an NSMutableDictionary (amongst other things) to a method in another class:

```
[self.shuttle makeAPICallAndReturnResultsUsingMode:@"login" module:@"login" query:credentials];
```

The NSMutableArray credentials is previously defined like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *credentials = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[credentials setObject:username forKey:@"username"];
[credentials setObject:password forKey:@"password"];
```

The method that receives it looks like this:

```
-(id)makeAPICallAndReturnResultsUsingMode:(NSString *)mode module:(NSString *)module query:(NSMutableDictionary *)query
```

The code works fine up until this point within the above method:

```
 [query setObject:self.sessionID forKey:@"session_id"];
```

At this point, the application terminates -- the console informs me of this exception:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '*** -[NSCFDictionary
>   setObject:forKey:]: method sent to an
>   uninitialized mutable dictionary
>   object'

This leads me to believe that I must initialize NSMutableDictionary in some way in my new method before I can access it, but I have no idea how. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to re-initialize the object in any way in the new method. You say the credentials array "is previously defined", but where is it defined? In the same method that calls `makeAPICallAndReturnResultsUsingMode`... ? Did you do anything with `query`in the makeAPI... method before the line that throws the exception?

Comment: It is previously defined just prior to the self.shuttle call that passes it to makeAPICallAndReturnResultsUsingMode -- per the OP I do add two values to the NSMutableDictionary, but that's it. And nope, nothing is done to it, the method literally looks like this:


    -(id)makeAPICallAndReturnResultsUsingMode:(NSString *)mode module:(NSString *)module query:(NSMutableDictionary *)query
    {
     [query setObject:self.sessionID forKey:@"session_id"];